# Java for loop ArrayList, indexoutofboundsexception

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

```
public static void main(String[] args){
........................
for(int i = 0; i<play.size(); i=i+1){
        System.out.println("the Winner is; " +Winners(play).get(i).name);
    }
}
```

This is the main method. i didnt write down Everything here, because its unnecesary. basically what i am doing, is that i am Calling `Winners` method that takes `ArrayList<Game>` as argument. `play` is of type `ArrayList<Game>`. on that i want to get the elements stored inside and get their name. so that the winners name is shown on screen. i for loop it because there can be several winners. depends on how many shares the same score.

```
private static ArrayList<Game> Winners(ArrayList<Game> gamers){
    ArrayList<Game> winner = new ArrayList<Game>();

    for(int i = 1; i==gamers.size(); i=i+1){

        if(gamers.get(i).getPoints()>gamers.get(i-1).getPoints()){     winner.clear();                              
            winner.add(gamers.get(i));
        }
        else if(gamers.get(i).getPoints()<gamers.get(i-1).getPoints()){ winner.clear();
            winner.add(gamers.get(i-1));
        }

        else if(gamers.get(i).getPoints()==gamers.get(i-1).getPoints()){ winner.clear();
            winner.add(gamers.get(i));
            winner.add(gamers.get(i-1));
        }

    }

    return winner;
}
```

the `Winners` method returns an `Arraylist<Game>`, which is where the gamer or gamers with top score are stored.
i loop through each on of the `gamers` and compare their `points` to each other. the one who has the most score gets stored in the `Winner` arraylist.

i clear the `winner` arraylist all the time some elements goes inside, because i only want the top Points stored there.

My issue is, i dont know if i am doing it correct. because i am getting error on
on the `System.out.println("the Winner is; " +Winners(play).get(i).name);`.
it says index 0 size 0 (indexoutofboundsexception)

Comment: Why doesnt my elements get stored inside the [tag:winner] [tag:arraylist]?

Comment: `for(int i = 1; i==gamers.size(); i=i+1){` doesn't do what I think that you think it does :)

Comment: btw you can use `i++` instead of  `i=i+1`

Comment: Hint, from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html : `When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.`

Comment: My first guess is that your winners function for some reasons is returning an empty arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 1; i==gamers.size(); i=i+1)
```

It means the loop will terminate when `i==gamers.size()` is false. At the first time when i=1, but gamers.size() is greater than 1. It never enters the loop. And returns empty list. When you trying to get one element from an empty list, you are getting the exception.

But I think you want to check `i < gamers.size()`. It might be:

```
for(int i = 1; i < gamers.size(); i++)
```

Again, you don't need `winner.clear()` in each if block. Rather you could:

```
private static ArrayList<Game> Winners(ArrayList<Game> gamers) {
    ArrayList<Game> winner = new ArrayList<Game>();

    for (int i = 1; i < gamers.size(); i++) {
        winner.clear();

        if (gamers.get(i).getPoints() > gamers.get(i - 1).getPoints()) {
            winner.add(gamers.get(i));
        } else if (gamers.get(i).getPoints() < gamers.get(i - 1).getPoints()) {
            winner.add(gamers.get(i - 1));
        } else { // last check when points are equal
            winner.add(gamers.get(i));
            winner.add(gamers.get(i - 1));
        }
    }
    return winner;
}
```

**N.B:** There is an issue in the approach of your `Winners()` method. You are iterating over `gamers` and adding a `winner` to the list. But every time you are clearing the list. That means you will get only the winner from last two players. Previous winners will be cleared. I think you need to recheck it.

As you are clearing the list, the size of `winner` list won't be same as the size of `play`. As a result, you will also get exception in this code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < play.size(); i=i+1) {
    System.out.println("the Winner is; " + Winners(play).get(i).name);
}
```

One fix could be:

```
ArrayList<Game> winnersList = Winners(play);
for(int i = 0; i < winnersList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("the Winner is; " + winnersList.get(i).name);
}
```

Comment: when i change it to i<= gamers.size(); i get Another indexoutofboundsexception. on the first if statements.

Comment: actually it would be  `i < gamers.size()`, cause if gamers.size() is 4, you need 3 check.

Comment: now after i changed what you said. i get error outofboundexception on the [tag:System.out.println("the Winner is; " +Winners(play).get(i).name);]

Comment: why is that? i dont understand

Comment: see my edited `N.B.` part. I think that's the reason. You need to rethink on clearing the list. What's the purpose of clearing?

Comment: thanks, i fixed it now! i put the call method.size() as an int variable. then i used that variable in the loop. and it fixed!